# Apache - only main domain's root is not working

Tags: apache

I've created a new domain and setup a php application on the webroot. All the following requests are working perfectly.

- /index.php
- /info.php
- /?anyting ( Note this, without index.php only query string is working )
- /css/app.css

Only the domain's root is not working `domian.in`

I have created an virtual host for the domain. I tried giving `DirectoryIndex index.php` also, but still it's not working. There is no htaccess and it's a fresh server setup.

Googled whatever was possible, couldn't get any solution.

And if i hit `domain.in` it's serving the apache's default page.

Comment: Did you enable `NameVirtualHost *:80`? Did you check `error_log`? Is  `selinux` enabled?

Comment: I have `<VirtualHost *:80>` on top of my domain's .conf file. Is this what you are asking ?

Comment: @alvits it's really weird, docs says `NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed` still adding this in the virtual host file worked! whole night passed fixing this issue. Thanks a lot dude!!

Comment: It wasn't weird. Any address/port combination appearing in multiple virtual hosts is implicitly treated as a name-based virtual host. `*:80` doesn't qualify as address/port combination, hence no implicit treatment as name-based virtual host. `NameVirtualHost *:80` explicitly treat the `<VirtualHost *:80>` as a name-based virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an virtual host you cant acces files outside the document root.
Maybe your html files (or others) are in a htdocs folder or something, you cant access htdocs/../

Comment: No it's just webroot with few php files.